# The domain of $f(x) = a^x + a^{-x}, a>0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, even-and-odd-functions

The domain of $f(x) = a^x + a^{-x}, a>0$.

**My attempt :**

Since the domain of the exponential function is $\mathbb{R}$, and since our function is the sum of two exponential functions and since the exponential function never attains $0$ value, then the domain of our function is $\mathbb{R}$. am I correct?

And it is an even function.correct?

Comment: Your $f(x)$ is properly defined for every $x\in\mathbb R$ so $\mathbb R$ can serve as its domain. The fact that value $0$ is not attained is not relevant.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi It is *given* that $a>0$.

Comment: did not see that @Vera .. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the domain is $\mathbb R$. But the fact that the exponential function never attains $0$ is not relevant here. All you need to know is that, for any real number $x$, both $a^x$ and $a^{-x}$ are defined.

And, yes, it is even: $f(-x)=a^{-x}+a^x=a^x+a^{-x}=f(x)$.

Comment: I am saying this because $a^{-x}$ will be in the denominator

Comment: @user593485 There is no denominator in $a^{-x}$.